# Window object is undefined after deploy to netlify

Tags: aws-lambda, netlify

I want to build an email verification. After the user registers, the user gets an email and clicks on it for verification purposes. The email-link invokes a netlify lambda function (api end point). Inside the link is a jwt token, which I decode on the backend. I used

```
window.location.href
```

for it and sliced the part I needed and decoded it. On localhost, it works fine, however, if I deploy it to netlify, I get an

```
window is undefined
```

error. I read that you have to check for

```
typeof window !== 'undefined'
```

However, if I add that to my lambda function I don't get any console.log statements.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
   let url = window.location.href
   let index = url.indexOf("=");
   let token = url.slice(index+1)
   console.log(token, 'token here')
  const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);

  console.log('confirm registration route triggered',decoded)
  
  if (decoded) {
    const { email } = decoded;
    console.log(decoded, 'decoded here')

    User.findOneAndUpdate({email: email}, {verified: true },(...e)=>{
      console.log(e)
    });
  } else {
    console.log('could not update user')
    //redirect user to page with message about email confirmation link expiration
    //and proposal to register again
  }

  
    console.log('confirm registration got invoked')
}
    return {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: "Oops"
    }
};
```

I read that the function first runs on the server when deployed and afterwards on the client. Seems like it does not run on my client, as I invoke the api-endpoint directly? I'm quite a beginner when it comes to API-Endpoints, thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

In case you have the same issue when deploying to netlify, you have to run

```
event.queryStringParameters
```

which gives you access to the query parts of your url.